# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'...previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

Im using SQL Server 2005 . I have 2 WITH Clauses in my stored procedure

```
WITH SomeClause1 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
WITH SomeClause2 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
```

But the error occurs

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

What are my options? Is there any splitter I don't know about?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use a comma to separate CTEs

```
;WITH SomeClause1 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
, SomeClause2 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
```

Comment: same goes for the SQL Server 2008 MERGE statement, too - it **must** be terminated with a semicolon!

Comment: gbn, you saved my hide. I was getting this error on a query component in Delphi, was stumped! Thanks again. And you Duncan.

Answer (score 18):

Forget about adding a ";" to the previous statement, like the error message says.  Just get in the habit of always coding it like: ";WITH" and you'll be fine...

```
;WITH SomeClause1 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
```

however, you must connect multiple CTEs with commas, but the ";WITH" always has a semicolon before it:

```
;WITH SomeClause1 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
,SomeClause2 AS
(
  SELECT ....
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with upgrading SQL Server Database COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL

ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Reference Link :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I changed the compatibility level to a newer one (2017 - 140).
It worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work for me.

In my case I'm using the CTE value within the RETURN clause of a table-valued user-defined function.  If I wrap the RETURN clause in BEGIN-END I get the same error message, but a bare RETURN() clause works okay.  I believe the error message is incorrect in this case.

This works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ft_SplitStringOnChar]
      (
      @s varchar(8000),
      @sep char(1)
      )

RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn AS TokenNumber,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS TokenString
    FROM Pieces
  )

GO  

This does not:

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ft_SplitStringOnChar]
      (
      @s varchar(8000),
      @sep char(1)
      )

RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
;
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn AS TokenNumber,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS TokenString
    FROM Pieces
  )
END
GO
```