# How can I combine two different CTEs

Tags: sql-server-2008

To make it simple, I have the following example:

```
;WITH myCTE (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
)
SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'

union all --this does not work with two With statements

;WITH myCTE2 (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
)
SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'BBICT'
```

Comment: This might not be the best example code, since you could just combine the 2 where clauses into 1 (i.e. CustomerID = 'ALFKI' or CustomerID = 'BBICT')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'...previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439123/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-previous-statement-must-be-terminated) This is about multiple CTEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH myCTE (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
), myCTE2 (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
)
SELECT Co FROM myCTE WHERE CustID = 'BBICT' 
union all
SELECT Co FROM myCTE2 WHERE CustID = 'ALFKI'
```

Edit:

Assumes OP picked a poor example.

Otherwise, all that is needed is

```
SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID IN ('ALFKI', 'BBICT' )
```

Comment: Didn't realize the second select statement after the union all was considered part of the CTE DML...very cool, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to common separate the two queries:

```
;WITH myCTE (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
)
,
myCTE2 (CustID, Co) AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers
)
SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'BBICT'
UNION
SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'
```

Comment: This is two separate queries. This is not what OP wants.