# SQL statement "WITH" doesn't work on Visual basic 6

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

I've just created a query which involves a selection on a table created by the WITH statement; I'd like to run in on a Visual Basic 6 application (connected to the database by an ADODB object) but I got an error message "incorrect syntax near the keyword "WITH", when I use the open method of a ADODB.recordset Object; it's like Visual Basic 6 doesn't understand this statement. How could I fix this? Is there an alternative way to perform the sql's WITH statement on Visual Basic 6?

Comment: You're going to have to share a lot more details with us: code, SQL statement and specifics of the error.

Comment: VB6 does not compile SQL anyway, so this question is simply "blaming the tool" and missing the target.

Comment: The problem is with your SQL-statement and/or the database engine you use. VB6 only provides the envelope for these and is ignorant  of database code.

Comment: I get the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword "WITH", when I use the open method of a ADODB.recordset Object

Comment: @Dharma - please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pound for a penny (in the absence of any more information and most likely incompleete error message) that the WITH does not have a preceeding `;` because of a SET statement or DECLARE or some such.

[Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'...previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439123/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-previous-statement-must-be-terminated/1439137#1439137)

Or OP is using SQL Server 2000 still...

Comment: Indeed I just put the semicolon, but I got another error: "Incorrect syntax near 'tmp'; the query starts with:

";WITH tmp (id_area_possesso,id_area_utente,livello_accesso) AS ("