# TSQL: WITH cteTABLE insert into other_table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, with-statement, insert-select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'…previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439123/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-previous-statement-must-be-terminated)

I want to select hierachical data and insert it in a table.
Therefore i need to use the WITH statment in my insert.

This works fine:

```
create table test_table
(
 id int
)   

with t_table 
as
(select 12345 wert)
insert into test_table (id)
select wert from t_table
```

But this generates a "wrong syntax near WITH keyword" error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_insert_test
AS
BEGIN

with t_table 
as
(select 12345 wert)
insert into test_table (id)
select wert from t_table

END
```

I guess T-SQL doesn't like the WITH keyword before the INSERT keyword.
How can i do this kind of insert in a stored procedure?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your post with the exact code & error?  Your first block of code has an error -- it either needs to be run as two statements, or have a GO put between the batches.  Further, I was able to execute the procedure without error.    While @JNK is correct that WITH has to be the first item in a batch, the only requirement I see here is to split the create table & the ad-hoc with-select.

Comment: @EBarr - the first statement works, but the second does not.  It sounds like you think the first statement didn't work.

Comment: That's correct.  If you cut and paste the first block there is a syntax error (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7. Incorrect syntax near 't_table').  It should have a "GO" between the create table and the WITH or a semicolon after the create table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CTE declaration needs to be the first command in the batch.

Just put a semicolon before the `WITH` and you should be fine:

`;WITH t_Table...`

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify *why* this is the case, the `WITH` keyword is used for query hints as well, such as `WITH RECOMPILE`, `WITH (NOLOCK)`, etc.  The query engine needs to know the intent of the `WITH` keyword, and the only way to signify that it represents a `CTE` is to ensure that the `CTE` declarations are the beginning of the batch.

Otherwise, you could have something ambiguous like:

```
SELECT Field
FROM MyTable
WITH CteName
As
(Select 1)
```

Without the statement terminator, `CteName` will be inappropriately read as a query hint applied to `MyTable`.

Comment: +1 : Or, alternatively put, make sure the preceding command is terminated with a `;`.  It's optional in most cases, but when using CTEs is a requirement to terminate the previous command 'correctly'.